# How to wrap column content to the bottom on scroll?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to wrap by lightgreen color `#left` "Scrolling Content" container to the bottom of the page when scrolling down? When there is no "Scrolling Content" in the left column it should be also stretched of 100% of page. I think that the right column under fixed container should also follow the same rules.

```css
.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-flow: column wrap; */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* align-items: stretch; */
  height: 100%;
}

.top {
  height: 60px;
}

.content {
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  height: 60px;
  background: tomato;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#left {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: 0 0 40%;

  /* justify-content: center; */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
}
#left > p {
  flex: 1;
}

#right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 60%;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: aqua;
  width: 60%;
  /* height: 100%; */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    <nav role='navigation'>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div id="left">
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div id="fixed">
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use overflow-y:scroll;

Comment: [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kew916fv/1/) updated

Comment: @bhv Why not as an answer?

Comment: @bhv that's it thanks! I was so close :)

Comment: @luzny `right` block should take rest of all visible space, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
/* .wrapper,  */   /* removed this */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-flow: column wrap; */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* align-items: stretch; */
  min-height: 100%;   /* changed here */
}

.top {
  height: 60px;
}

.content {
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  height: 60px;
  background: tomato;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#left {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: 0 0 40%;

  /* justify-content: center; */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
}
#left > p {
  flex: 1;
}

#right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 60%;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: aqua;
  width: 60%;
  /* height: 100%; */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    <nav role='navigation'>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div id="left">
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
      <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div id="fixed">
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
        <p>This content should not scroll</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've removed redundant blocks and styles. Here is minimal HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

nav {
  height: 60px;
  background: tomato;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#left {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 60%;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: aqua;
  top: 60px;
  width: 60%;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

```html
<nav role='navigation'>
</nav>

<div class="content">
  <div id="left">
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
    <p>Scrolling Content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="fixed">
      <p>This content should not scroll</p>
      <p>This content should not scroll</p>
      <p>This content should not scroll</p>
      <p>This content should not scroll</p>
      <p>This content should not scroll</p>
      <p>This content should not scroll</p>
      <p>This content should not scroll</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```